# Checkbox to change font weight not working - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to insert a checkbox into a form to change the font weight of text in a div.

My javascript is as follows:

```
function boldText(checkBox,target) { 
  if(checkBox.checked){ 
    document.getElementById("lineOne").style.fontWeight = "bold"; 
  }
  else { 
    document.getElementById("lineOne").style.fontWeight = "normal"; 
  } 
}
```

And my html like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="boldText(this,textToBold)"> 
<div id="lineOne">Change text to bold</div>
```

What is wrong here. I cant seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove target it is undefined so it gives an error send id of div in single quate as follow

```
 <script>
    function boldText(checkBox,target){ if(checkBox.checked){
document.getElementById(target).style.fontWeight = "bold"; }
else
{ document.getElementById(target).style.fontWeight = "normal"; } }
</script>
<input type="checkbox" onclick="boldText(this,'lineOne')">
<div id="lineOne">Change text to bold</div>
```

refer [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hemant1027/Z8DdQ/)

Comment: Thanks a million. Little things always seem to be the hardest for me to fathem. Learning alot since i started.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete target in function argument and textToBold when you call it

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/xArCc/1/
or
http://jsfiddle.net/xArCc/2/
There you go. The target should've been "lineOne" when you make the call.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line to :

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="boldText(this,'textToBold')">
```

Because "textToBold" is a string.